Form Numbers as Images
So essentially I haven't found a way to be able to have my dice rolls (represented by a form box with randomised digits from 1-6 (inclusive)), represented as images instead of number, however I do not know JS and would like to be able to do this with CSS, PHP and HTML. I also have been unable to style the checkboxes, sorry if I seem ignorant. Here is the script:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
    body {
        background-color: black;
        font-family: helvetica;
        text-align: center;
        background-size: 105%;
        background-position: center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DfkFYgNLSmw/maxresdefault.jpg);
    }
    .header {
        z-index: 10;
        background-color: black;
        color:White;
        padding: 27px;
        padding-top: 52px;
        padding-bottom: 52px;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 12.5%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        padding-left: 45%;
        padding-right: 45%;
    }
    .die {
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 35%;
        bottom: 50%;
        transform: translate(7%, -50%);
        
        
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .die > div {
        background-color: black;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: white;
    }
    .die > div > div {
        background-color: dodgerblue;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 15px;
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    .button {
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 60%;
        left: 50%;
        padding-top: 9px;
        padding-bottom: 9px;
        padding-left: 25px;
        padding-right: 25px;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background-color: gold;
    }
    .button:active {
        background-color: goldenrod;
    }
    .scroll {
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 12px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        z-index: 10;
        height: 2px;
        width: 320px;
        background-color: white;
        mix-blend-mode: difference;
    }
    .statistics {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 250px solid transparent;
        border-right: 1750px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 850px solid white;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -100%;
        left: -25%;
        z-index: 9;
        mix-blend-mode: difference;
        /* Make sticky text something something so it drags down from the header (y) */
    }
    .underneath {
        height: 650px;
        width: 150%;
        background-color: black;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -212%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
</style>
<head>
<title>Yahtzee</title>
</head>
<div class="header">
    <h1>Yahtzee</h1>
</div>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$message = '';
if (isset($_POST["dice1check"])) {
$dice1check = 'checked';
$dice1 = $_POST["dice1"];
} else {
$dice1check = '';
$dice1 = rand(1,6);
}
echo"";
if (isset($_POST["dice2check"])) {
$dice2check = 'checked';
$dice2 = $_POST["dice2"];
} else {
$dice2check = '';
$dice2 = rand(1,6);
}

echo"";
if (isset($_POST["dice3check"])) {
$dice3check = 'checked';
$dice3 = $_POST["dice3"];
} else {
$dice3check = '';
$dice3 = rand(1,6);
}

echo"";
if (isset($_POST["dice4check"])) {
$dice4check = 'checked';
$dice4 = $_POST["dice4"];
} else {
$dice4check = '';
$dice4 = rand(1,6);
}

echo"";
if (isset($_POST["dice5check"])) {
$dice5check = 'checked';
$dice5 = $_POST["dice5"];
} else {
$dice5check = '';
$dice5 = rand(1,6);
}

echo"<br>";
echo $message;
?>

    <form name="diceroller" method="post" action="<?php htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">
<div class="die">
    <div>
        <label for="dice1">Dice 1</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="dice1" class="textbox" value="<?php echo $dice1;?>">
        <br>
        <label for="dice1check">Check to keep</label>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="dice1check" <?php echo $dice1check;?>>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br> <br>
    <div>
        <label for="dice2">Dice 2</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="dice2" class="textbox" value="<?php echo $dice2;?>">
        <br>
        <label for="dice2check">Check to keep</label>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="dice2check" <?php echo $dice2check;?>>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br> <br>
    <div>
        <label for="dice3">Dice 3</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="dice3" class="textbox" value="<?php echo $dice3;?>">
        <br>
        <label for="dice3check">Check to keep</label>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="dice3check" <?php echo $dice3check;?>>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br> <br>
    <div>
        <label for="dice4">Dice 4</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="dice4" class="textbox" value="<?php echo $dice4;?>">
        <br>
        <label for="dice4check">Check to keep</label>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="dice4check" <?php echo $dice4check;?>>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br> <br>
    <div>
        <label for="dice5">Dice 5</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="dice5" class="textbox" value="<?php echo $dice5;?>">
        <br>
        <label for="dice5check">Check to keep</label>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="dice5check" <?php echo $dice5check;?>>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <br> <br>
    <button class="button">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Roll" class="button">
    </button>

    </form>
    
<div class="scroll">
    <header1>SCROLL FOR STATISTICS</header1>
</div>
<div class="statistics">
</div>
<div class="underneath">
    
</div>
</imp>
</body>
</html>

I tried using JS but failed 

Currently, the dices class (which contains the core dice elements, including the checkboxes) and the "Roll" button are hidden (overlapped) by other elements on your page.
For your information, z-index is the CSS property that controls the stacking order of overlapping elements on a page.
So you may specify the class dice to have a larger z-index value say z-index:50000 and the button to have z-index:50001 (so that they will not be overlapped by other elements on top) , and then it will work
So, based on your original code:
(1) Change
    <button class="button">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Roll" class="button">
    </button>

to
    <button class="button" style="z-index:50001">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Roll" class="button">
    </button>

and
(2) change
 .die {
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 35%;
        bottom: 50%;
        transform: translate(7%, -50%);        
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

to
 .die {
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 35%;
        bottom: 50%;
        transform: translate(7%, -50%);
        z-index:50000;        
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }


?? Idk what code you're looking at, but those elements are not overlapped for me. Also what's with the insane number z-index?

Please try adding what you called the insa*e number z-index as I have mentioned and it will work - For your information, I always test every answer I posted and I am sure this one works

but this isn't the question tho :(

I removed all PHP code and here is javascript version of code. In addition to that  Try to not use position  absolute if it is not necessary.
<body>
<div class="header">
    <h1>Yahtzee</h1>
</div>




<form name="diceroller" method="post" action="<?php htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">
    <div class="die">
        <div>
            <label for="dice1">Dice 1</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="dice1" class="textbox" value="<?= rand(1,6) ;?>">
            <br>
            <label for="dice1check">Check to keep</label>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="dice1check">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br> <br>
        <div>
            <label for="dice2">Dice 2</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="dice2" class="textbox" value="<?= rand(1,6); ?>">
            <br>
            <label for="dice2check">Check to keep</label>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="dice2check">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br> <br>
        <div>
            <label for="dice3">Dice 3</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="dice3" class="textbox" value="<?= rand(1,6); ?>">
            <br>
            <label for="dice3check">Check to keep</label>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="dice3check">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br> <br>
        <div>
            <label for="dice4">Dice 4</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="dice4" class="textbox" value="<?= rand(1,6); ?>">
            <br>
            <label for="dice4check">Check to keep</label>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="dice4check" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br> <br>
        <div>
            <label for="dice5">Dice 5</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="dice5" class="textbox" value="<?= rand(1,6); ?> ">
            <br>
            <label for="dice5check">Check to keep</label>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="dice5check">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br> <br>
    <button class="button">Roll</button>
</form>
<div class="scroll">
    <header1>SCROLL FOR STATISTICS</header1>
</div>
<div class="statistics">
</div>
<div class="underneath">

</div>

<script>
    let dice1check = document.querySelector("input[name='dice1check']")
    let dice2check = document.querySelector("input[name='dice2check']")
    let dice3check = document.querySelector("input[name='dice3check']")
    let dice4check = document.querySelector("input[name='dice4check']")
    let dice5check = document.querySelector("input[name='dice5check']")

    let dice1 = document.querySelector("input[name='dice1'")
    let dice2 = document.querySelector("input[name='dice2'")
    let dice3 = document.querySelector("input[name='dice3'")
    let dice4 = document.querySelector("input[name='dice4'")
    let dice5 = document.querySelector("input[name='dice5'")


    function randomise(diceElement, checkElement) {
        if (!checkElement.checked) {
            let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
            diceElement.value = random
        }
    }

    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        randomise(dice1, dice1check)
        randomise(dice2, dice2check)
        randomise(dice3, dice3check)
        randomise(dice4, dice4check)
        randomise(dice5, dice5check)

    })


</script>


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
